# Tracking software for movies watched, episodes seen, games played, etc

Tags: windows, file-management

I have many movies and series' episodes and games on my PC. I want an app that could tell me which thing I've watched or played. I wish after completing something I can change it's status as done. It should be not limited to this but also for assignments done etc.

Basically I'm looking for software that adds a property to every file/folder which can only have two values.

I have Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[trakt.tv](https://trakt.tv/) scrobbles (tracks) everything you watch through a media center, including your local files (not your games). [This](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file) may help you tag files.

Comment: eve if they are on my external hard disk? i got an error 404 btw

Comment: Dunno m8, don't see why not. Ask on their forums

Comment: Yes my liegeeee